# C++ static member reinitialized after initialization

Tags: c++, templates, static, c++17

Im am trying to implement a design of a "HasUtility" template class allowing to create templated static member (utilities) and maintening a list of all utilities (base classes)

Here is the code:

StaticUtilityBase.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class StaticUtilityBase {
public:
    static std::vector<StaticUtilityBase*> all;
    StaticUtilityBase() {
        all.push_back(this);
        printAllState();
    }
    static void printAllState() {
        std::cout << "All size is " << all.size() << ", address is " << &all << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T> class StaticUtility : public StaticUtilityBase {};

template <typename T> class HasUtility  {
public:
    static StaticUtility<T> utility;
};

template <typename T> StaticUtility<T> HasUtility<T>::utility;
```

TemplateUtility.cpp:

```
#include "StaticUtilityBase.h"
std::vector<StaticUtilityBase*> StaticUtilityBase::all;
```

and the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "StaticUtilityBase.h"
class A {};
class B {};
int main() {
    std::cout << "Initializations done" << std::endl;
    StaticUtilityBase::printAllState();
    HasUtility<A>::utility; //Tell to the compiler that the static member is used so the constructor
    HasUtility<B>::utility; // of utility is used before main execution, during initializations
}
```

When executing I have the following result:

```
All size is 1, address is 0x562942baa1f0
All size is 2, address is 0x562942baa1f0
Initializations done
All size is 0, address is 0x562942baa1f0
```

All size should still be 2 at the end.
Looks like "all" is reinitialized after the "utility" members initialization!
The address is the same so I think it is the same object. Maybe it has been copied from an empty one?? Any help welcome!

I use gcc and C++17

Comment: Are you sure the print order is correct?

Comment: Looks like classic SOIF (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) to me. You have no control in when `all` is initialised and its probably initialised after you use it (which resets it back to empty although its obviously undefined behaviour)

Comment: Modules are usually initialized in alphabetical order.  Try renaming TemplateUtility.cpp, to see the effect it has on your program. The best way to avoid this issue is with a pragma, as in adding, for msvc `#pragma init_seg(lib)` in  TemplateUtility.cpp...  
I dont' know the exact syntax for gcc or clang.  But I'm sure someone who reads this comment will know it by heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a static object (in this case `StaticUtilityBase::all`) from the constructor of a different static object (in this case `template <typename T> StaticUtility<T> HasUtility<T>::utility;`).

As there is no ordering guarantee between initialisation of different static objects across translations units what you are trying to do won't work.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof for more information.

And easy way to verify this is to add a second static object to `StaticUtilityBase` which prints out when it gets constructed:
`static int printer = []()->int{std::cout << "Initing StaticUtilityBase\n"; return 0;}()`

Comment: Thank you for this correct answer! I am used to java where static init occurs lazily at runtime (but can lead to infinite recursion) so I didn't see the point.

Comment: I did also discover that adding "inline" to the static members tells the compiler to initialize them lazily, it solves the problem. Also the declaration outside the class in no more necessary